# Ubuntu VPS in sleep mode / standby?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, webserver, sleep, vps

I currently have a problem with my VPS (ubuntu 14.04.4). When I access it after hours the first time again via HTTP or SSH it takes a few seconds until it reacts, sometimes it is even too long, so it timeouts. As soon as the server "woke up", it works properly and fast.

So I contacted my provider, they said they don't struggle with any technical issuses, so I should check my server if a "sleep mode" is somehow activated.

I am not sure whether or not the provider says the truth so, how can I check if my server runs any modules that makes it sleep after a certain amount of hours?

I by the way didn't change anything, didn't install anything new.

Thanks a lot!